# Posting variable values from inside HTML forms inside PHP loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

How can i post variable values from inside HTML form which is inside PHP loop.

A snippet of code I've written so far is below:

```
 while($row=oci_fetch_array($sql))
              {

        echo "
    <body>
        <fieldset style=\"  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #C4C4C4; 
                            border:0; 
                            width:420px;
                            height:125px;\">
    <form action=\"buffer.php\" method=\"POST\">
    <strong>Code:</strong> <input type=\" text\" value=\" $row[0]\" name=\" code\" disabled ><br>
    <strong>Course Name:</strong> <input type=\" text\" value=\" $row[1]\" name=\" namec\" disabled><br>
    <strong>Credit:</strong> <input type=\" text\" value=\" $row[2]\" name=\" credit\" disabled ><br>
    <strong>Section:</strong> <input type=\" text\" value=\" $row[3]\" name=\" section\"disabled ><br>
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Assesment \" name=\"addasmnt\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit Attendance \" name=\"editasgmnt\">
    </br> </fieldset> </form> </body>
        ";
           $i=$i+1;          
            }
```

While in 'buffer.php';

```
<?php
session_start();
    $roll= $_SESSION['roll'];
    print_r($_SESSION);echo "<br>";
    print_r($_POST);echo "<br>";
    print_r($_GET);echo "<br>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

The output of buffer.php is

```
Array ( [roll] => hammad.hassan ) 
Array ( [addasmnt] => Add Assesment ) 
Array ( ) 
Array ( [addasmnt] => Add Assesment )
```

The `$_POST` is not showing any variables.

Comment: Are you saying after you submit it the `$_POST` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not getting `POST`ed because inputs are `disabled`.

As W3C states in [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12):

> Disabled controls cannot be successful.

First thing what user agent does in processing form data is:

> **Step one:** Identify the successful controls

But as said above, `disabled` elements wont be on this list.

**Three options:**

1. Remove `disabled` attribute
2. Use `readonly="readonly"` instead of disabled
3. Add `<input type="hidden">` with same values and names. Then change original inputs names to something else.

**Hidden inputs example**

```
<?php
echo '
<body>
  <fieldset style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #C4C4C4; border:0; width:420px; height:125px;">
    <form action="buffer.php" method="POST">
      <strong>Code:</strong> <input type="text" value="'.$row[0].'" name="code_dummy" disabled><br>
      <strong>Course Name:</strong> <input type="text" value="'.$row[1].'" name="namec_dummy" disabled><br>
      <strong>Credit:</strong> <input type="text" value="'.$row[2].'" name="credit_dummy" disabled><br>
      <strong>Section:</strong> <input type="text" value="'.$row[3].'" name="section_dummy"disabled><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Assesment" name="addasmnt"><input type="submit" value="Edit Attendance" name="editasgmnt">
      </br>
      <input type="hidden" name="code" value="'.$row[0].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="namec" value="'.$row[1].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="credit" value="'.$row[2].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="section" value="'.$row[3].'">
    </form> 
  </fieldset> 
</body>
';
```

Read more about [disabled controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled).

**In loop**

Since you are using this with loop, which will result in multiple same name inputs. `POST` them as `array`s. Add `[]` to input names.

For example:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="code[]" value="'.$row[0].'">';
```

This will give you array of all `code` input values. To set a key for value, add it inside of `[]`. For example `[$i]`.

But I presume your `$i` starts with `0`, so this is not needed in this case, since keys will be automatically assigned (if empty) starting from `0`.